# MYSQL query to get average rating value for review site?

Tags: mysql, select, average

This is regarding a review website.

I'm trying to sort a list of items based on their overall average rating value. I do understand there is an AVG function but not sure how to incorporate it. Also, the review_category_list is in my query to deal with displaying other data and isn't specifically relevant to the rating question.

Here is the query I have so far but need to somehow work in averaging the rating for each item:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
item_id
), item_name, des_location, address, city, state, zip, country, dedicated, item_desc, abv, item_type
FROM review_category_list, review_items
LEFT JOIN review ON review.review_item_id = review_items.item_id
WHERE category_id =14
AND category_id != -1
AND cat_id_cloud =14
ORDER BY review.rating DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `review_category_list` (
  `cat_id_cloud` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `catorder` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `parent` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `abv` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `olditemid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'item_id from the review_items_orig table',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id_cloud`),
  UNIQUE KEY `category` (`category`,`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `review_items` (
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `item_desc` longtext NOT NULL,
  `item_type` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `category` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT '-1',
  `sortorder` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `item_image` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `item_aff_url` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `item_aff_txt` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `item_aff_code` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `des_location` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `lat` float(10,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `lon` float(10,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `dedicated` enum('yes','no','dontknow') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `des_contact` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `chapterid` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `oldcat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `review` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rating` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `summary` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `review` longtext NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `location` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `review_item_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `visitorIP` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_added` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `useful` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notuseful` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `approve` enum('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sig_show` enum('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
  `rating2` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_image` varchar(75) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `oldid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `id_2` (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `summary` (`summary`,`review`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6443 ;
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Tim

Comment: If you also provide some test data, this would be nearly a perfect question

Comment: ...and if you provided a desired result too, then it really would be a perfect question.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function - but perhaps you figured that out already

Comment: Also, you gave us review_items twice, but we never saw review. :-( See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: ...and does review_category_list relate to one or other of the other tables in any particular way?

Comment: There is an AVG function

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need a MySQL query, but I suppose computing average rating each time you show the list is not the best way to achieve what you want: showing items based on their average rating.

Instead, what I would do is actually add the 'average_rating' and 'number_of_reviews' fields to the 'item' table.

Then, upon a new review insertion for an item, you can just update the item table the following way:

1. Update the 'average_rating' field using the formula: (item.average_rating*item.number_of_reviews + review.rating)/(item.number_of_reviews+1) (Of course you need to take care of corner cases when there is no reviews so item.number_of_reviews is 0 etc.)
2. Increment the 'item.number_of_reviews' field

Next time you need to get a list of items ordered by average rating, you just do very simple `SELECT` query with `ORDER BY` clause, something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY average_rating DESC;
```

I think this whole approach would work much faster, be more reliable and supportable.